# hackerrank ~no response on stdout~(java) || 2D arrays-Ds

Tags: java, data-structures

There was a problem when finding the sum of all hourglasses in a 6X6 matrix and printing the max sum. This is my code. What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int matrix[][] = new int[6][6];
        int result[] = new int[17];

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            result[i] = 0;
        }
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
                if (i <= 4 & j <= 4) {
                    result[k] = matrix[i][j] + matrix[i][j + 1] + matrix[i][j + 2] + matrix[i + 1][j + 1] + matrix[i + 2][j] + matrix[i + 2][j + 1] + matrix[i + 2][j + 2];
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        sc.close();

        int max_no = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
            if (max_no < result[i]) {
                max_no = result[i];
            }
        }

        System.out.println(max_no);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
if (i <= 4 & j <= 4)
```

Above line threw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. So,

```
if (i < 4 & j < 4)
```

the solution is correct but can anyone provide a solution with more optimised and general?

---

My solution is working for 5 cases out of 7
maybe its not working for -ve values. The below input gives wrong answer

```
-1 -1 0 -9 -2 -2

-2 -1 -6 -8 -2 -5

-1 -1 -1 -2 -3 -4

-1 -9 -2 -4 -4 -5

-7 -3 -3 -2 -9 -9

-1 -3 -1 -2 -4 -5
```

I got the code to work. The problem was in initializing the `max_no` and `length` of result which should be 16 not 17,

```
int max_no = result[0]; //correct now will work for -ve numbers
```

Waiting for an optimized code or another solution...

Answer (score 0):

```
process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

var input_stdin = "";
var input_stdin_array = "";
var input_currentline = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', function (data) {
    input_stdin += data;
});

process.stdin.on('end', function () {
    input_stdin_array = input_stdin.split("\n");
    main();    
});

function readLine() {
    return input_stdin_array[input_currentline++];
}



function main() {
    var arr = [];

    for(arr_i = 0; arr_i < 6; arr_i++){
       arr[arr_i] = readLine().split(' ');
       arr[arr_i] = arr[arr_i].map(Number);
    }

    var sums = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        for (var y = 0; y < 6; y++) {
            if (x + 2 < 6 && y + 2 < 6) {
                var firstLine = arr[x][y] + arr[x][y+1] + arr[x][y+2];
                var secondLine = arr[x+1][y+1];
                var thirdLine = arr[x+2][y] + arr[x+2][y+1] + arr[x+2][y+2];
                sums.push(parseInt(firstLine) + parseInt(secondLine) + parseInt(thirdLine));    
            }

        }
    }

    process.stdout.write(Math.max.apply(Math, sums) + '');
}
```

this is my code in js